# Saving Google Sheets as xlsx file and manipulating with loses .gs scripts written

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets

I have a lot of Google Sheet files that have some .gs scripts in them. I wanted to change them in mass using a Python script and downloaded them all and ran the Python script to do the changes.

After it's all done, I realized that downloading the Google Sheets somehow loses the .gs scripts that are tied to the file (I think because Google Sheets and xlsx files are different and somehow xlsx doesn't support .gs scripts). Is there any way that I can run my Python script on those Google Sheets without losing the .gs scripts?

P.S: Don't ask my why use both Python scripts and .gs scripts :)

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `Is there any way that I can run my Python script on those Google Sheets without losing the .gs scripts?`. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: I want to run my Python script on the Google Sheet. But if I download to save them on my laptop, .gs scripts are not saved. So I think I need a way to run the Python script directly on Google Sheets or maybe write another script to add gs scripts back after the Python script is run and files are uploaded again.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: How about using the Sheets API with [python](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)? So there would be no need to download it.

Comment: I think this was the workaround I was looking for. Thank you. Surprised that I didn't find it in my initial research....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Consideration

The .xlsx file you can download from Google APIs won't contain the bound Google Apps Script file. The script files are separate entities from their containers even though they are related.

### Solution

You can use the Google Apps Script API with Python to manage your Apps Script Projects. In order to do so you will need the Scripts Ids.

To retrieve the Script Ids of a bound Google Apps Script file you will have to use the Apps Script method `.getScriptId()`. In this case I suggest to create an Apps Script standalone projects that retrieves the Script Ids and saves them so you can use them with your Python script.

Once you have all the Script Ids you can adapt your Python script to perform the changes.

### References

[.getScriptId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getscriptid)

[Get Apps Script Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getscriptid)

[Get Apps Script Projects Content](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent)

[Update Apps Script Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent)